# Log to file in Asterisk: append with newline

Tags: logging, log-files, asterisk

(I am testing on Asterisk 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1)

I am using the following format to append to a logfile, according to the [documentation](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+FILE):

```
same => n,Set(FILE(/tmp/mylog.txt,,,a)=my-log-message)
```

But this does not append a newline. So I am trying:

```
same => n,Set(FILE(/tmp/mylog.txt,,,al)=my-log-message)
```

But this does not append (instead, it just overwrites - surprisingly, since the documentation says that this should append!).

How can I append **and** make sure that a newline is added after the log message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
same => n,Set(FILE(/tmp/mylog.txt,,,al,u)=my-log-message)
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but   some explanation is welcome. Thanks in advance. - Also it is convention to format commands/configuration settings as code: http://serverfault.com/editing-help